# How to insert data by using td id

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my PHP code is below.

```html
<table width="100%" >                   
    <tr  width="100%" class="bgcolor_02">                       
        <th ROWSPAN="2" >SUBJECTS </th>                     
        <th COLSPAN="2" >EXAMS </th>                        
        <th COLSPAN="2" >PROJECTS </th>                     
    </tr>
    <tr class="bgcolor_02">
        <th id="1E"> 1.EXAM</th>
        <th id="2E"> 2.EXAM</th>
        <th id="1P"> 1.PROJECT</th>           
        <th id="2P"> 2.PROJECT</th>                           
    </tr>                

<?php
    $myexamresults = $db-> getrows (" SELECT * FROM `es_exam_result` WHERE `es_studentid` = '".$_SESSION['eschools']['user_id']."'  ORDER BY `es_examorder` ASC  ");    
    $pre_subjects=subjectnameByClass($es_subjectshortname);         
    foreach ($pre_subjects as $ndsdersliste ) {
        $subjeid=$ndsdersliste['es_subjectid']; ?>

       <tr > <td ><?php echo $ndsdersliste['es_subjectname']; ?></td>        
       <?php       
       foreach ($myexamresults as $ndsmyexam) {         
          $puan="";
          if( $ndsdersliste['es_subjectname'] == $ndsmyexam['es_subjectname'] )     {                   
                $examname = $ndsmyexam['es_examname'];
                $puan  =  $ndsmyexam['es_puan'];            
                if ($examname =="1.Exam"){ ?> <td  headers="1E"  ><?php {echo $puan  ;} ?> </td>  <?php  } 
                if ($examname =="2.Exam"){ ?> <td  headers="2E" ><?php {echo $puan  ;} ?> </td>  <?php  }   
                if ($examname =="1.Project"){ ?> <td   headers="1P" ><?php {echo $puan  ;} ?> </td>  <?php  }   
                if ($examname =="2.Project"){ ?> <td   headers="2P" ><?php {echo $puan  ;} ?> </td>  <?php  } 
            } }  ?>               
        </tr>
    <?php      } ?>
            </table>
```

I can get exam results from database. But I can not insert correct data under headers. If a student have just "1.Project" result, It is showing under "1.Exam". How to insert under correct title. Thanks..

Comment: Is it possible to include an example of the generated HTML, so we can play with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create empty `<td>` if there is no result to have the same number of `<td>` for each `<tr>`:

```
<tr > <td ><?php echo $ndsdersliste['es_subjectname']; ?></td>  
<?php
$td = [];
foreach ($myexamresults as $ndsmyexam) {         
    $puan="";
    if( $ndsdersliste['es_subjectname'] == $ndsmyexam['es_subjectname'] )     
    {                      
        $examname = $ndsmyexam['es_examname'];
        $puan  =  $ndsmyexam['es_puan'];            

        if ($examname =="1.Exam") { $td['1E'] = $puan ; }
        if ($examname =="2.Exam") { $td['2E'] = $puan ; }
        if ($examname =="1.Project") { $td['1P'] = $puan ; }
        if ($examname =="2.Project") { $td['2P'] = $puan ; }
    } 
}

if (isset($td['1E'])) echo '<td headers="1E">'.$td['1E'] .'</td>' ; else echo '<td headers="1E"></td>' ;
if (isset($td['2E'])) echo '<td headers="2E">'.$td['2E'] .'</td>' ; else echo '<td headers="2E"></td>' ;
if (isset($td['1P'])) echo '<td headers="1P">'.$td['1P'] .'</td>' ; else echo '<td headers="1P"></td>' ;
if (isset($td['2P'])) echo '<td headers="2P">'.$td['2P'] .'</td>' ; else echo '<td headers="2P"></td>' ;

?>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Gokhan I've updated the answer. This is the code of the `<tr>`.